# How to modify properly the URL with mod rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got a site with dynamically generated URL-s, but they all follow this pattern:
The text after the domain it's either:

```
/index.php?content=99.Contact
```

or

```
/index.php?content=00.Home&article=00.Lorum+ipse.json
```

I'm looking for a solution where:

The results would be something like:

```
domain/Contact
domain/home/Lorum+ipse
```

Note, that the 00 and 99 are numbers, always two digits.

I've seen some other questions and resolutions so far, but was never able to implement them on my site. 
So far I have some bad bots and site rippers blocked in my .htaccess as per advised by: http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess13.shtml, and some other rewrite but not sure what it is for.

What should my final .htaccess file look like to achieve the user friendly URL-s?
This is what I have now.

```
#Blocking bad bots and site rippers (aka offline browsers) - http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess13.shtml
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BlackWidow [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bot\ mailto:craftbot@yahoo.com [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ChinaClaw [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Custo [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DISCo [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Download\ Demon [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^eCatch [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EirGrabber [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailSiphon [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailWolf [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Express\ WebPictures [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ExtractorPro [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EyeNetIE [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^FlashGet [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetRight [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetWeb! [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go!Zilla [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go-Ahead-Got-It [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GrabNet [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Grafula [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^HMView [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} HTTrack [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Stripper [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Sucker [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Indy\ Library [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^InterGET [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Internet\ Ninja [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JetCar [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JOC\ Web\ Spider [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^larbin [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^LeechFTP [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mass\ Downloader [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^MIDown\ tool [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mister\ PiX [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Navroad [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NearSite [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetAnts [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetSpider [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Net\ Vampire [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetZIP [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Octopus [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Explorer [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Navigator [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^PageGrabber [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Papa\ Foto [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pavuk [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pcBrowser [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^RealDownload [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ReGet [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SiteSnagger [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SmartDownload [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperBot [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperHTTP [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Surfbot [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^tAkeOut [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Teleport\ Pro [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^VoidEYE [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Image\ Collector [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Sucker [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebAuto [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebCopier [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebFetch [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebGo\ IS [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebLeacher [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebReaper [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebSauger [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ eXtractor [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ Quester [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebStripper [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebWhacker [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebZIP [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Wget [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Widow [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WWWOFFLE [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xaldon\ WebSpider [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus 
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gyulasoos.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.gyulasoos\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The current rewrite rule is to redirect non-www requests to www-requests. How do you handle the requests in your PHP-file? Regarding the numbers, would `/index.php?content=Contact` fetch the correct page or is the `99.` important?

Comment: The two digits and the . are important. :D 00.Home, 11.About, 99.Contact etc. Same with the second example: artilce=11.Something.json. The 11. is imprtant.

Comment: Can there be two other digits in front with the same name, like `77.Contact`? Is it always the same digits for the same content (do `Content` always have `99.` in front of it?

Comment: It can, but it won't! :D

Comment: This is a special site, it's not using databases. Instead, reads a folder structure, which will be translated into the main menu of the site and each json file inside that structure is an article or content. The numbers are there to define the order in which the menu items or articles should appear. They may have the same numbering, in which case they will be ordered alphabetically.

Comment: The problem is that if you have an URL like `foo.com/Contact` and the app needs `foo.com?content=99.Contact` (with the number) to work, and the numbers can change, there is no way for the rewrite to know what to rewrite to.

Comment: what if we keep the number? So in the end it would stay 99.Contact but without the index.php? and any & symbols? domain.com/00.Home/11.Article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are two different scenarios (one or two url fragments), we can set up two rules for that:

```
# Put these lines last in your htaccess

# Ignore the rules if the file or folder actually exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]

# This will match /foo
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?content=$1 [L,QSA]

# This will match /foo/bar and append .json on the last one
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?content=$1&article=$2.json [L,QSA]
```

Comment: here is this site: gyulasoos.com I've modified the htaccess, and one thing happened and one didn't: the main landing page, where there is nothing else after the domain is not working anymore, but any other links are the same as they were before the modification. :(

Comment: OK, so... it is working, however it breaks my homepage (where nothing follows the domain, and some of the embedded images are no longer working. I'm definitely in the right path now, just have to find the root of the problems. Thank you!

Comment: sorry, this blody htaccess makes me crazy! Is there a way, to ignore when there is only the domain name and nothing else?

Comment: @GyulaSoós - My bad. I forgot the first set. I have updated the answer and it will now ignore all requests to valid files or folders, which means that / and all paths to your assets should work.

Comment: Oh! YOU'RE A STAR!